# Angular Material MatDialog not being destroyed propertly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having issues with my MatDialog view not being destroyed correctly when I exit.  The first time works correctly.  Then I exit and bring up the dialog again; two overlays are created. Third click, three overlays.  I believe I am not destroying the object correctly or something, but I can't find anything on the Angular Material website or anything on the internet for that matter.

Screenshot of the multiple dialogs being created:

[image]

Code to invoke dialog:

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

constructor(dialog: MatDialog) {}

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(StockDetailComponent,
        {
            data: {
                      ticker: ticker, stockDetail: results, intraDayChartAvailable: intraDayChartAvailable,
                      dailyChartAvailable: dailyChartAvailable, weeklyChartAvailable: weeklyChartAvailable,
                      monthlyChartAvailable: monthlyChartAvailable
                  }
        });
```

Can I explicitly do something in this event to ensure proper destruction?

```
dialogRef.afterClosed()
```

Dialog Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material';

  export class StockDetailComponent {
      public chart: ChartComponent;
      public ticker: string;
      public stockDetail: Stock;
      public intraDayChartAvailable: boolean;
      public dailyChartAvailable: boolean;
      public weeklyChartAvailable: boolean;
      public monthlyChartAvailable: boolean;
      constructor(
        private stockComponentSharedService: StockComponentSharedService,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<StockDetailComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
          this.chart = new ChartComponent();
          this.ticker = data.ticker;
          this.stockDetail = data.stockDetail;
          this.intraDayChartAvailable = data.intraDayChartAvailable;
          this.dailyChartAvailable = data.dailyChartAvailable;
          this.weeklyChartAvailable = data.weeklyChartAvailable;
          this.monthlyChartAvailable = data.monthlyChartAvailable;
          this.intraDayChartAvailable ?      this.generateChart(this.stockComponentSharedService.getCachedStockData(this.ticker, 0),
          this.stockComponentSharedService.getCachedStockLabels(this.ticker, 0)) :
          this.generateChart(this.stockComponentSharedService.getCachedStockData(this.ticker, 1),
          this.stockComponentSharedService.getCachedStockLabels(this.ticker, 1));
       }

  public hideStockDetails(): void {
    this.chart.populateData([], []);
    this.stockComponentSharedService.clearTicker(this.ticker);
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

Any help is appreciated